# How do I write a class function that returns a value as soon as the class is called?

Tags: python, arrays, class, magic-methods

I have to complete the following challenge:

> The object created from a class C contains an array of integers, passed in when the object is created. Define a text representation of an object that returns an expression that sums up all the numbers in an array, in the order as in the array.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> C([5,12]) -> "5+12=17"
> C([6,0,15]) -> "6+0+15=21"
> ```

I tried to return do this in the `__init__()` function but it cannot return a value.

```
class C():
    def __init__(self, array):
        self.array = array

        # ctreating the text
        sum = 0
        text = ""
        for i in range(len(array)):
            sum += array[i]
            text += str(array[i])
            if i < len(array):
                text += "+"
        text += f"={sum}"

        # trying to return the ready text
        return(text)

C([5, 12])
```

It kind of works if I `print()` it intead of return but I'm supposed to return the value.

Comment: I think the question is asking you to provide a `__str__` method.  But it is badly worded.

Comment: Given the problem description, perhaps `__str__()` is meant, although a custom method would also make sense.

Comment: "text representation of an object" smells like `__repr__` rather than `__str__` to me, but they're often equivalent.

Comment: The return value of `__init__()` is ignored. The function named after the class always returns an instance of the class (unless the class has a `__new__()` method, which is a very advanced feature).

Answer (score 1):

You are very close, you just need to separate initialization in `__init__` and computations in another function:

```
class C():

    def __init__(self, array):
        self.array = array

    def print_sum(self):
        # creating the text
        sum = 0
        text = ""
        for i in range(len(self.array)):
            sum += array[i]
            text += str(self.array[i])
            if i < len(self.array):
                text += "+"
        text += f"={sum}"

        # trying to return the ready text
        return(text)
        

print(C([5, 12]).print_sum())
```

Another possibility as @John Gordon mentioned is:

```
class C():

    def __init__(self, array):
        self.array = array

    def __str__(self):
        # creating the text
        sum = 0
        text = ""
        for i in range(len(self.array)):
            sum += array[i]
            text += str(self.array[i])
            if i < len(self.array):
                text += "+"
        text += f"={sum}"

        # trying to return the ready text
        return(text)
        

print(C([5, 12]))
```

Now just printing the class will automatically print the string representation of the sum.

Comment: And the body of the method can be written in one line: `return f"{'+'.join(map(str, self.array))}={sum(self.array)}"`.